# Simple html templating for small sites with grunt

Tags: gruntjs, mustache

Looking for a simple html templating solution for small sites.
I really want to do some basic includes (similar to some super simple PHP) that generate out to flat html. I had tried using [Assemble.io](http://assemble.io) but it seems to contain so much more.

For reference I'm coming from [mixture.io](http://mixture.io) which has some really easy templating but since it is a subscription I cant have that be the way our whole office makes sites. I have also seen middleman but I feel like node is just a lot easier to deal with.

I feel like there is a way to do what I'm looking for with mustache alone but my javascript is not very good. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into Cabin

http://colinwren.github.io/Cabin/

Workflow uses Grunt and they added livereload support in the last release. Good alternative to using Jekyll.